# What is difference between YARN and hive2 queues?

Tags: hive, hadoop-yarn, scheduler, capacity

What is difference between `yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.queues` and `hive.server2.tez.default.queues`?

Comment: Hi @ShwethaJog, if any answer of the below answers has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In short :**

> `hive.server2.tez.default.queues` values are subset of 
>   `yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.queues`(If capacity scheduler is configured in YARN, if not other scheduler) values.

---

**Detailed answer:**

> **hive.server2.tez.default.queues:** (Default: empty)
>
> A list of comma separated values corresponding to YARN queues of the
>   same name. When HiveServer2 is launched in Tez mode, this
>   configuration needs to be set for multiple Tez sessions to run in
>   parallel on the cluster.
>
> This **does NOT mean that queries can't be issued to other "existing"
>   queue** defined in capacity scheduler. [source](https://streever.atlassian.net/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=4390918)
>
> ---
>
> **yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.queues:**
>
> The CapacityScheduler has a pre-defined queue called root. All queueus in the system are children
>   of the root queue. Further queues can be setup by configuring
>   yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.queues with a list of comma-separated
>   child queues. [source](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/CapacityScheduler.html), [setting up capacity scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39999015/how-to-limit-dynamic-self-allocation-of-resources-in-hadoop-cluster-under-yarn)

So, the scope of `hive.server2.tez.default.queues` is upto Hive queries only, but `yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.queues` scope will be for all the components(like MapReduce and Spark) in the cluster which are using YARN as Resource Manager.

Comment: Thanks @mrsrinivas